# Error in Zuul SendErrorFilter during forward

Tags: netflix-zuul

When my Zuul Filter is unable to route to a configured URL, the 'RibbonRoutingFilter' class throws a ZuulException saying "Forwarding error" and the control goes to the 'SendErrorFilter' class.

Now when the SendErrorFilter class tries to do a forward, another exception happens during this forward call.

```
dispatcher.forward(ctx.getRequest(), ctx.getResponse());
```

The exception happening during this forward call is

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: UT010023: Request org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.pre.Servlet30WrapperFilter$Servlet30RequestWrapper@6dc974ea was not original or a wrapper
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:103) ~[undertow-servlet-1.1.3.Final.jar:1.1.3.Final]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.post.SendErrorFilter.run(SendErrorFilter.java:74) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:1.0.0.RELEASE]
    at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter.runFilter(ZuulFilter.java:112) ~[zuul-core-1.0.28.jar:na]
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.processZuulFilter(FilterProcessor.java:197) ~[zuul-core-1.0.28.jar:na]
```

Finally when the control comes to my custom ZuulErrorFilter , i do not get the original exception. Instead the exception object i get is the one that occurs during the forward.

**Update:**
       I found that a errorPath property can be configured to point to a Error Handling Service. If it is not configured, Zuul by default looks for a service named /error and tries to dispatch to that service. Since we did not have any service for /error , the dispatcher.forward()  was throwing error.

**Question**
     How can we skip this fwd to an error handling service ? We have a ErrorFilter to log the error. We do not want to have a error handling service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had faced the same issue and there is a simple solution to fix the Undertow "eating" the original exception, following my blog post:

http://blog.jmnarloch.io/2015/09/16/spring-cloud-zuul-error-handling/

You need to set the flag allow-non-standard-wrappers to true. In Spring Boot this is doable through registering custom UndertowDeploymentInfoCustomizer. Example:

```
@Bean
public UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory embeddedServletContainerFactory() {
    UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = new UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
    factory.addDeploymentInfoCustomizers(new UndertowDeploymentInfoCustomizer() {
        @Override
        public void customize(DeploymentInfo deploymentInfo) {
            deploymentInfo.setAllowNonStandardWrappers(true);
        }
    });
    return factory;
}
```

Now regarding the question, either way I would highly encourage you to implement your own ErrorController, because otherwise you may experience odd Spring Boot behaviour (in our setup - ralying on the default was always generating the Whitelabel error page with 200 HTTP status code - which never happens on Tomcat in contradiction) and in this way was not consumable by AJAX calls for instance.

Related Github issue: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/524

Comment: we recently switched to Tomcat and after seeing your response, i tried replicating the issue with Tomcat and realized it was happening only with Undertow. Since we are going to go ahead with Tomcat, we will not use this but, it is good to know and hope this will help others who are using underTow. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Is there any way to return a Custom Message when SendErrorFitler has failed ?  when the dispatcher.forward() to /error in SendErrorFilter fails (because we haven't yet defined our custom ErrorFilter), i was trying to return a custom JSON message as response from our Post Filter.  But looks like the response has been already committed because of the forward() which is giving {"timestamp":1443516371981,"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException","message":"Forwarding error"}

Comment: Here is the next issue i am facing now after fixing the above.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860126/how-to-create-a-custom-httpservletresponsewrapper-to-return-a-custom-string

Comment: Could you post the entire zuul filter code? In which phase are you handling the request? https://github.com/Netflix/zuul/wiki/Writing-Filters#filter-types